# How to set a value to Unbound Column cell ? (SetRowCellValue) Grinview Winforms Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I can able to set value to Bounded Column from Db.

Using this code

```
int c = a + b;
```

`gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["boundcolumn"], c);`

But I want to Set the this c value to Unbound Column. this code not working to Unbound Column. How to set value to Unbound Coulmn ?

Answer (score 5):

Unbound column get its values using the GridView's [CustomUnboundColumnData](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event handler.  Unbound column values are not preserved by the grid, they are passed to this event handler so that a developer can catch this moment and save it.  Please refer to the [SetRowCellValue and Unbound Column.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q438654) ticket which is also devoted to this issue.

**Update**

Please note the following.  Unbound columns are intended to allow the grid to manipulate with data (group, sort, calc summary and so on) which is not the part of the gridControl's DataSource.  It means that data for an unbound column should be stored by a developer himself in any external storage.  When the `SetRowCellValue`  method is called, the `CustomUnboundColumnData` event is raised with the `e.IsSetData` attribute equal to true.  In this case, the developer MUST save this data somewhere and then return it within the `CustomUnboundColumnData` event when the `e.IsGetData` equal to true.  I do not see the code where you save the value. So, you defenetely need to add this code.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Platon thanks for answering, But I tried that CustomUnboundDataColumnEvent but it get data but wont set in Unbound Column ??

Comment: you are obviuously doing something wrong.  Please post your code for the CustomUnboundColumnData event handler

Comment: `private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
        {`

Comment: `GridView view = sender as GridView;`

Comment: `e.Value = getTotalValue(view, e.ListSourceRowIndex);`

Comment: Thanks a lot I get an idea now.